# AWS Glue/Athena - S3 - Table partitioning

Tags: amazon-web-services, parquet, aws-glue, amazon-athena

Lets assume I have an external table registered in AWS Glue, which is in S3 and queried by Athena.
The best practice is to partition the data. So in a normal case, I have two seemingly same options,

```
1. /data/_path/yyyy/mm/dd/col1/col2/data.parquet
2. /data/_path/col1/col2/yyyy/mm/dd/data.parquet
```

i'd assume either way the data scanned/queried by Athena is same for a given col1 and/or col2.
But which one is preferred and why?

Comment: There is not enough information in this question for answers to be meaningful. Which alternative is better depends on what `col-1` and `col-2` are, how the process that produces the data works, and what queries you will run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred way is from the least granulated variable to the most granulated variable.

Usually is the first answer because you have fewer years than months, fewer months than days, fewer days than col1s and fewer col1s than col2s.

But if you have any specification that requires col1s and col2s come first, and then years, this will not be a problem.

Comment: +1 for generalizing it to "least granulated variable to the most granulated variable", even in case of col1 and col2, they can also be generalized the same way. But when the path components become independent of each other (for example yyyy, mm, dd is independent of col, col2) where they appear in the path is more or less based on the uses case.

Answer (score 1):

If data is generated based on yyyy/mm/dd fast, then option #1.

For example, your generated data in a month happens on every single day from 01 to 30 (or 29,31) so the pattern is good.

Or another example, your generated data happens at hour level so the pattern yyyy/mm/dd/hh would be great.

If data is generated based on col1/col2 fast, then option #2

For example, your generated data changes based on col1 (class id)/col2 (student id) and data belong to student id follow yyyy/mm/dd so you can go ahead with col1/col2/yyyy/mm/dd

Or you can think of, if your use case use col1/col2 more often in term of querying data, so option #2 is a good option.

To me if we compare about performance of 2 options, I don't think it is significant.